# flutter - Dart Map in Map called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this

```
var _subscription = Map<String, Map<String, StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot>>>();
```

When I tried to call this

```
_subscription[id][userId] = Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).snapshots().listen((snapshot)
```

console says this.

> The method '[]=' was called on null

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: Can u try something like: Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).snapshots().listen((snapshot) ?? []

Comment: Thank you for comment  it's still the same:(   Any idea?

Comment: I think there is no snapshot is being returned by snapshots() call, that's why your "snapshot" object is null. We need to find out why snapshots() returns null if so, could u please check?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Actually there are three incoming userId and first one return snapshot but after first one, throw this error. So I think it's about Map. What do you think?